# Computer not booting and giving an error

Tags: boot, amd-graphics, gpu-driver

My computer is using Ubuntu 22.10 with kernel 6.1. My GPU is an AMD Radeon RX 7900 XT. It gives me this error when I try to turn it on.

```
spi-nor spi0.0: BFPT parsing failed. Please consider using SPI_NOR_SKIP_SFDP when declaring the flash
```

I tried the supported 5.19 kernel and the issue still happened, but when I unplugged my GPU it booted so it might be a driver error.

I tried rebooting in recovery mode and reinstalling drivers, but it still didn't work so I'm not sure what the issue is. Also, I get the same issue when using integrated graphics, but there's a lot of weird visual errors (possibly due to software rendering). Also the driver I've been using is for Ubuntu 22.04 and I'm using 22.10. It hasn't given me any issues until now, but I thought I should still mention it.

I did some research and I think the error has something to do with PCIE, which explains my GPU not working

I disabled the spi-nor driver and my computer still didn't boot, when I tried booting with kernel 5.19 my computer gave the following errors

```
amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: failed to add dm ip block(dce_HWIP:0x30200)
amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: fatal error during GPU init
```

I ran dmesg while booted into kernal 6.1 and it gave me similar error

```
[    7.208279] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for amdgpu/psp_13_0_0_sos.bin failed with error -2
[    7.208282] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: failed to init sos firmware

[    7.208297] [drm:psp_sw_init [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to load psp firmware!

[    7.208478] [drm:amdgpu_device_ip_init [amdgpu]] *ERROR* sw_init of IP block <psp> failed -2

[    7.208701] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: amdgpu_device_ip_init failed

[    7.208711] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: Fatal error during GPU init

[    7.208730] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: amdgpu: finishing device.

[    7.208941] amdgpu: probe of 0000:03:00.0 failed with error -2

[    7.208959] [drm] amdgpu: ttm finalized
```

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: I tried and the issue still happened, but when I unplugged my gpu it booted so it might be a driver error

Comment: What GPU are you using? Can you provide some more information about the system?

Comment: My gpu is an amd Rx 7900xt

Comment: no this does not answer my question

Comment: good point, the drivers that I installed were designed for Ubuntu 22.04 and even though they have worked so far, that could be what broke

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, apparently this issue is related to missing kernel modules, I installed them with this guide here
https://catwithcode.github.io/Blog/2022.12.16_Radeon_7900XT-XTX_On_Linux/Radeon_7900XT-XTX_On_Linux.html